# send file to server axios

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, axios

I am trying send file to server with laravel api and react but the response is null this my code in frontend

```
 let File;
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    File = (e.target.files[0]);
}
const send = () => {
       const formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("media", File);
       console.log(formData)
       try {
           PostRequest.post("/upload-post", {"media": formData}).then(r => console.log(r.data)).catch((e) => console.log(e));
       } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
       }
   }
```

and my header :

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Accept":"application/json",
    "Authorization": Token
}
```

and network tab
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL7gl.png)

File log
[File log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFMOD.png)

Comment: check if the file is there on the onChangeHandler first

Comment: @Jithin I add log of it in the question